# Flask SocketIO bad Request 400

Tags: flask, heroku, socket.io, web-deployment, flask-socketio

My flask chat application was working fine on localhost development server. But when i hosted my app on heroku nothing is working properly and i checked console to find lots of Bad Requests.
Both GET and POST requests are getting 400 errors.

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1592543494128-64&sid=6740d63740c24f6ca6bd7234325a7c21 HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://flack-ma.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36"
```

```
"POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1592543547379-72&sid=8eadd5ac2bcf4ff1a414d878aa506839 HTTP/1.1" 400 11 "https://flack-ma.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36"
```

App worked fine on localhost.
[Deployment Link](https://flack-ma.herokuapp.com)
[Project Repo](https://github.com/UMuktesh/Flack)
I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Probably a CORS related issue. Have you set up CORS properly?

Comment: I didnt use CORS dunno what is it? Is it required for server? Because local server worked

Comment: i tried default CORS(app) and cors_allowed_origin='*' still not working

Comment: Enable Socket.IO logs to see what is the cause of these 400 errors then.

Comment: Changing Procfile did the trick.

Comment: Hi i am having same issue, can you please help ? @MuktesharyanUppala

Comment: @MervinHemaraju the settings for heroku server are in the Procfile file. I was using incorrect details which were causing the error.

Comment: @MuktesharyanUppala can you help me out friend. I am having same issue and it is not working for me. I have a bounty on my question also. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189422/flask-docker-container-socketio-issues